# What was Alvin' s father feeling disenchanted about?

Tags: the-x-files

In the fantasy movie, *The X files (1998)*, Special Agent Fox Mulder has been accused of the Dallas bombings. Alvin sees Fox urinating behind the hotel and introduces himself:

> Old friend of your father's. At the State Department we were fellow 
>   travelers. **But his disenchantment outlasted mine**.

Comment: I doubt most people consider *The X-Files* a fantasy; it's certainly intended to be science fiction.

Comment: @RDFozz - Did you watch the series? Sure, there are aliens and whatever…but there’s a lot more than that.

Comment: @Adamant - Point taken - sometimes, Scully does basically give up on a real scientific explanation for things. However, for most things, some sort of hand-wavy-type quasi-scientific explanation is given. There are some urban fantasy aspects, and the science fiction elements are sometimes more what I'd call science fantasy. A crossover between the X-Files and, say, Buffy wouldn't have been out of the question. And, I haven't seen the second movie; the first was part of the "alien invasion" storyline, as I recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Original question title was, "What exactly did Alvin's father have disenchantment on?"]

Based on the quote, Alvin is saying that, like Fox's dad, he was not pleased with some of the things he saw going on in the government. However, Alvin decided to live with those things he didn't like, whereas Fox's dad did not (or, at least, took longer before doing so.

No actual "enchantment" is involved. The definition of "disenchantment" is:

> a feeling of disappointment about someone or something you previously respected or admired; disillusionment